# Network Icon not visible on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, shell, user-interface

The network icon for my Local Area Connection has suddenly disappeared. I am using Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Already tried:

- Open the properties window for the connection from the "Network Connections" folder. Select "Show icon in notification area when connected". Did not help.
- Open the "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" window and uncheck the "Hide inactive icons" box. Did not help.
- Open the "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" window, check the "Hide inactive icons" box to enable the "Customize" button. Click said button to open "Customize Notifications" window. Under "Past Items", look for the network icon and set it's state to "Always show". Did not help.

None of the above worked. Any thing else I could try?

**Edit:** The icon has reappeared after having disconnected and reconnected to the network, but I'd still like to know a more predictable solution.

Comment: In the connection properties, do you have the option to show the icon even if there is a connection problem ?

Comment: Did it happen only once, or several times ? Did Explorer crash before, or at least the process in charge of displaying the tray icons ? Were all usual icons present as well, in this case ?